# Xoscope not showing signals

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have Xoscope loaded with 16.04 on a Gateway NE71B. It loads and seems to recognize the right and left stereo sides of my sound card. It does not recognize a USB sound card I tried. I built a probe adapter and when connected to an approximately 10 hz source, I see nothing on the screen except some random noise. The noise stays when I unplug the adapter. I tried randomly varying the scale, time base and sample rate with no success. I also tried "padsp xoscope".

Pulse Audio Volume Control is also loaded. It recognizes the stereo sound card and the USB sound card. When connected to the probe adapter/ 10 hz source, I see a definite heart beat on the volume bar. I can adjust that volume bar up and down. The heart beat stops when I unplug the source. This works on both sides of the built in stereo sound card as well as the USB mono card.

Are there any thoughts on how I can get Xoscope to show those signals?  Or are there any alternatives.  I'm trying to measure the time difference between two signals.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything I could find on line, I reloaded pulse audio and ran "padsp xoscope".  After slowing down the time scale several steps, the signals were there.  This seems linked to the lack of /dev/dsp.  I'm just not sure if it was the reload or something else I tried.

Things tried:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
sudo apt-get install osspd
sudo apt-get install osspd-alsa
osspd xoscope
sudo apt-get install alsa-oss
then type: aoss xoscope
sudo modprobe snd-pcm-oss